# Call JavaScript file from html form

Tags: javascript, html

I am sure this has been asked somewhere before, not exactly finding it though. I'm learning html and JavaScript.

I have a script to validate form entries that is now in its own validate.js file as a function. I am wondering how I would call this JS file from my form?

Also, may I put several functions in one .js file?

Comment: You don't call a file. You load the file using `<script>` tags, and then you call the functions that are defined in the file.

Comment: If you're learning Javascript from a tutorial, I can't believe it doesn't show this basic setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you attach the js functions to the HTML elements through event listeners. If you want the user to press a button to validate the form, then you attach an event listener to the button saying that when it receives a click, it should execute the function. 
It is more common to attach the listener to the form inputs. You can do that using the onchange event or the oninput event. Something like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById(`elementId`);
input.addEventListener('change', validateEmail)
```

or

```
input.addEventListener('input', validateEmail)
```

You could use any functions you want, this was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

To put javascript file /script refer [where to put javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)
and for form validation refer [form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) (there are many tutorials but this one is simple)

you can put several functions in a single .js file.